# How to create AutoMap feature for FluentNHibernate based on attributes?

Tags: linq, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to use map mechanism, based on property attribute marking, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class DomainSignatureAttribute : Attribute { }

public class SomeThing {
    [DomainSignature]
    public virtual string SomePropertyForMapping {get;set;}
    [DomainSignature]
    public virtual int OtherPropertyForMapping {get;set;}

    public virtual string OtherPropertyWithoutMapping {get;}
}
```

So in ClassMap children I want to realise this method, that map all properties, marked by DomainSignatureAttribute attribute:

```
protected void MapPropertiesWithStandartType()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            object[] domainAttrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DomainSignatureAttribute), true);

            if (domainAttrs.Length > 0)
                Map(x => property.GetValue(x, null));
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a small problem with Linq. When FluentNHibernate builds mapping (Cfg.BuildSessionFactory()) it break with

> Tried to add property 'GetValue' when already added.

exception. As I undestand I need to rebuild Linq expression: `x => property.GetValue(x, null)` into correct form.

Please don't suggest to use AutoMap feature and don't suggest to use manual mapping.

Comment: You can use auto-mapping + auto-mapping override (IAutoMappingOverride) and then defining mapping.IgnoreProperty(...) just for the properties that you don't want to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var domainproperties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DomainSignatureAttribute), true).Length > 0);

foreach (var property in domainproperties)
{
    Map(Reveal.Member<T>(property.Name));
}
```